# How to get start/end point of a dm-script line annotation (Component)?

Tags: annotations, dm-script

I want to use:

`Component NewLineAnnotation( Number top, Number left, Number bottom, Number right )`

The problem is that the line always runs in the direction from the top-left to the bottom-right.

However, I need the line to go from bottom-right to top-left. 
And I also need to be able to get the accurate direction from an existing one.

It seems silly that the command is not:
`Component NewLineAnnotation( Number start_x, Number start_y, Number end_x, Number end_y )`

but surely there is a way to get the direction of the line annotation?

`void ComponentGetRect( Component comp, NumberVariable top, NumberVariable left, NumberVariable bottom, NumberVariable right )`

does not have such a detail.

Comment: Please take some time to review your question and fix the formatting issues.

Comment: Brian, I am new to this.  What is the issue?

Comment: The question has recently been edited by someone else to make it better. I can only give advice now and say please look at the difference between your original post and the edited one, then consider those visual changes next time you ask a question. It will help you get an answer faster.

Comment: @EVoelkl. Ideally, a post is formated and phrased such that a new reader sees at a glance what the question is and if it matches what he is interested in as well. Source-code is generally formatted. Also, if you find the time, please 'accept' one of the given answers (click in between the arrows on the left of it) to indicate that the question is answerd. Choose the one you think helped you the most and/or will help a new reader best. Simiilarly, you can up/down vote answers (and questions) if you approve/dissapprove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an interestings question!
I think the behavior of `ComponentGetRect()` is doing correct thing but mislabeling the variables names in the documentation. While it says that it returns you a rectangle as top-left to bottom-right coordinates, it actually returns you the Y/X start coordinate and the Y/X end coordiante pair of the Annotation. (For other types of annoations, this then is [TLBR] ). Note that it is Y/X not X/Y! This is confusing, but to keep it in line with the more general "component" object.

Similarly, the signature variables names for `NewLineAnnotation()` are wrong, as they are obvisoulsy giving a start to end direction, as you can easily try out when using arrow-annotations instead. (See example script below.)

> **You can defenitly set the direction of a created line or arrow annotation using:**
> `Component NewLineAnnotation( Number StartY, Number StartX, Number EndY, Number EndX )`
> `Component NewArrowAnnotation( Number StartY, Number StartX, Number EndY, Number EndX )`
> **Similarly, you should use for reading the postions:**
>
> `ComponentGetRect( NumberVariable StartY, NumberVariable StartX, NumberVariable EndY, NumberVariable EndX )`

Now, and alternative way of getting start and end coordinates would be the *control point* of the component, and the F1 help documention explicitly lists the control point ID values:
[image]

So, the presumably correct way would be to ask the componet of the coordinates of the specified *control point* using:

`Boolean ComponentGetControlPoint( Component comp, Number loc, NumberVariable x, NumberVariable y )`

However, giving this a test (see script below) it does not actually work for the *control point* ID values `1` and `2`. It seems that the two control points for start/end of a line have not been implemented with the command.

But, you can use the "Top/Left" *control point* `4` for getting the start value and the "Bottom/Right" *control point* `7` for getting the end value. Again, this just matches the same somewhat irregular mapping of "line/arrow" annotations on the regular components.

> **Alternatvive way of getting a start point XY:**
> `Boolean ComponentGetControlPoint( Component comp, 4, NumberVariable x, NumberVariable y )`
> **Alternatvive way of getting a end point XY:**
> `Boolean ComponentGetControlPoint( Component comp, 7, NumberVariable x, NumberVariable y )`

---

#### Test script used

```
// Control Point constants. See F1 help documentaton ("Component Object" Overview)
number kLineStart   = 1 // = start point of line
number kLineEnd     = 2 // = end point of line
number kTopLeft     = 4 // = top-left for rect, or start point for line
number kBottomRight = 7 // = bottom-right for rect, or end point for line

number sx = 50
number sy = 30
number ex = 400
number ey = 200
number sizeX = 500
number sizeY = 500

void PrintAnnoInfo( component anno )
{
    if ( !anno.ComponentIsValid() ) return
    number t,l,b,r
    anno.ComponentGetRect( t, l, b, r ) 
    // note that it is return StartY, StartX, EndY, EndX into TLBR!
    
    number type = anno.ComponentGetType()
    Result( "\n\n Component of type " + type + ":" )
    Result( "\n\t Position rect: " + t + " / " + l + " / "+ b + " / "+ r )
    Result( "\n\t\t { TOP / LEFT / BOTTOM / RIGHT }" )
    
    number sx, sy, ex, ey
    if ( !anno.ComponentGetControlPoint( kLineStart, sx, sy ) )
        Result( "\n INVALID Control point for annotation type. ( " + kLineStart + " ) " )
    else
        Result( "\n\t Start point (X/Y): " + sx + " / " + sy )
    if ( !anno.ComponentGetControlPoint( kLineEnd, ex, ey ) )
        Result( "\n INVALID Control point for annotation type. ( " + kLineEnd + " ) " )
    else
        Result( "\n\t End point (X/Y)  : " + ex + " / " + ey )

    if ( !anno.ComponentGetControlPoint( kTopLeft, sx, sy ) )
        Result( "\n INVALID Control point for annotation type. ( " + kLineStart + " ) " )
    else
        Result( "\n\t Start point (X/Y): " + sx + " / " + sy )
    if ( !anno.ComponentGetControlPoint( kBottomRight, ex, ey ) )
        Result( "\n INVALID Control point for annotation type. ( " + kLineEnd + " ) " )
    else
        Result( "\n\t End point (X/Y)  : " + ex + " / " + ey )
    
Result( "\n\n" )
    
}

// clear workspace and created dummy
EGUPerformActionWithAllShownImages( "Delete" )
ClearResults()
Result( "Component direction test:\n\n" )
image img := Realimage( "Test", 4, sizeX, sizeY )
img.ShowImage()
imageDisplay disp = img.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)

// Creating and adding line-Annotation
number UseArrow
useArrow = TwoButtonDialog( "In this test use", "Arrows", "Lines" )
string msg
msg = "\nAdding " + (useArrow?"arrow":"line") + ":"
msg += "\n from (" + sx + " / " + sy + ") to (" + ex + " / " + ey + ")"
msg += "\n { from (Ex/Ey) to (Sx/Sy) }"
Result( msg )
OKdialog( msg )

Component anno
if ( useArrow )
    anno = NewArrowAnnotation( sy, sx, ey, ex ) // note that it is YX!
else
    anno = NewLineAnnotation( sy, sx, ey, ex )  // note that it is YX!

anno.ComponentSetForegroundcolor(1,0,0)
disp.ComponentAddChildAtEnd( anno )
anno.PrintAnnoInfo()

msg = "\nAdding " + (useArrow?"arrow":"line") + ":"
msg += "\n from (" + ex + " / " + ey + ") to (" + sx + " / " + sy + ")"
msg += "\n { from (Ex/Ey) to (Sx/Sy) }"
Result( msg )
OKdialog( msg )

if ( useArrow )
    anno = NewArrowAnnotation( ey, ex, sy, sx ) // note that it is YX!
else
    anno = NewLineAnnotation( ey, ex, sy, sx )  // note that it is YX!


anno.ComponentSetForegroundcolor(0,1,0)
disp.ComponentAddChildAtBeginning( anno )
anno.PrintAnnoInfo()
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the details in earlier great answer I looked more and found this to be the situation - I am using GMS 3.

The command for creating a line as a component via:

```
NewLineAnnotation( Number top, Number left, Number bottom, Number right )
```

could be described better as:

```
NewLineAnnotation( Number sX, Number sY, Number eX, Number eY )
```

But there is another source of potential confusion.  When looking for the Get() command for the coordinates, these commands are listed:

```
void ComponentGetBoundingRect( Component comp, NumberVariable t, NumberVariable l, NumberVariable b, NumberVariable r )

void ComponentGetRect( Component comp, NumberVariable top, NumberVariable left, NumberVariable bottom, NumberVariable right ) 

void ComponentGetRectInView( Component comp, NumberVariable top, NumberVariable left, NumberVariable bottom, NumberVariable right )
```

All 3 commands claim the order: top, left, bottom, right, but only the first and the last commands do.  The second command could again be better described by

```
ComponentGetRect(Number sX, Number sY, Number eX, Number eY)
```

I had mixed up the command NewLineAnnotation() with ComponentGetBoundingRect() and that caused some real issues.  I feel a better description in the manual might help avoid such issues.

As a summary, here is some code I used to demonstrate the different functionalities to myself.

```
image front := CreateFloatImage("", 800, 800)
front.setZoom(.4)
front.ShowImage()
component frontComponent = front.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)

component solid_Line_orange = NewLineAnnotation(700, 10, 500, 200);
frontComponent.ComponentAddChildAtEnd(solid_Line_orange)
solid_Line_orange.ComponentSetForegroundColor(1,.66,0);
component solid_Line_white  = NewLineAnnotation(500, 10, 700, 200);
frontComponent.ComponentAddChildAtEnd(solid_Line_white)

number sx, sy, ex, ey
number l_top, l_left, l_buttom, l_right
solid_Line_orange.ComponentGetRect( l_top, l_left, l_buttom, l_right );

Result("\n\n")
Result("using:  ComponentGetRectangle();\t actual convention: (start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y)\n")
Result("orange line set at: \t(700, 10, 500, 200);\n")
Result("orange line found at: \t(" + l_top + ", " +  l_left + ", " + l_buttom + ", " + l_right + ")\n")
solid_Line_white.ComponentGetRect( l_top, l_left, l_buttom, l_right ) 
Result("white line set at: \t(500, 10, 700, 200); \n")
Result("white line found at: \t(" + l_top + ", " +  l_left + ", " + l_buttom + ", " + l_right + ")\n")

Result("using:  ComponentGetBoundingRectangle();\t actual convention: (top, left, bottom, right)\n")
solid_Line_orange.ComponentGetBoundingRect( l_top, l_left, l_buttom, l_right ); 
Result("orange line found at: \t(" + l_top + ", " +  l_left + ", " + l_buttom + ", " + l_right + ")\n")
solid_Line_white.ComponentGetBoundingRect( l_top, l_left, l_buttom, l_right ); 
Result("white line found at: \t(" + l_top + ", " +  l_left + ", " + l_buttom + ", " + l_right + ")\n")

Result("using:  ComponentGetBoundingRectInView();\t actual convention: (top, left, bottom, right)\n")
solid_Line_orange.ComponentGetBoundingRectInView( l_top, l_left, l_buttom, l_right ); 
Result("orange line found at: \t(" + l_top + ", " +  l_left + ", " + l_buttom + ", " + l_right + ")\n")
solid_Line_white.ComponentGetBoundingRectInView( l_top, l_left, l_buttom, l_right ); 
Result("white line found at: \t(" + l_top + ", " +  l_left + ", " + l_buttom + ", " + l_right + ")\n")
```

This solves the problem for me.  Hope this helps somebody else as well.  And maybe a better description in the manual could help as well.

Comment: Right. I mixed it up yesterday. (Corrected my answer). So it is above all: A mistake in the documentation which needs to be fixed. It's reported now.